# Submit page to itself and allow to enter more data

Tags: php, mysql

I have two sections on my PHP form. One section allows to enter Customer information(Name, address etc.) and another section allows to enter Customer product and it's details(about 15 text boxes) and submit button. The user can enter unlimited product and details for the same Customer.  I have 2 tables. Customer table and Cust_Products table. So I think I have to submit the Form to itself and keep the first section data and clear out the second section. What is the best practice to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Best practice of dealing with dynamic forms is **using Ajax**.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs citation needed

Comment: You can save your data in session variable (it's more safe because some destructive user actions, such as page reloading, etc. can ruin data he entered). Or use AJAX (as you were adviced). Or store somehow other users data because it's best practice (for safety and covenience) to handle data chunks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could add a check to see if the form has been submitted to itself, and output the appropriate form, taking care to store the posted values along the way.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{ // product & details form 
}
else
{ // customer information
}
```

Comment: Thanks. first time I have to save the Customer and product details. My save logic should be on the same page. right? Do you have any examples?

Comment: This would get into where you need to tailor it for your needs.  An option is to store data to the session as you go, and then dump it into a database when finished.  I would look to Google for that method.  Regarding the save logic...if you are looking to separate presentation from data storage, then yes, it should be separate.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the customer id in a session, after it's created the first time. If you open the form again, you check for the id in the session and if it's set, you display the customer's details and the form to add another product.

If the session is not set (or the user want's to create a new customer: provide a link to reset the id in the session), you provide the form for creating a customer.

Answer (score 0):

Give your forms the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="$_POST['user_name']">
```

This way you can keep on using the same username if you repost to the same page, without the user having to enter it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this when removing an object to force the user to click Delete twice to confirm that they *really* want to delete something, but I'd imagine it should work out pretty well for your situation as well

```
function yourmodule_FORM_ID($form, &$form_state) {
    if(!isset($form_state['storage']['confirm'])){
        //this is where your first form goes
    }
    else{
        //this is the second form
    }
}

function yourmodule_FORM_ID_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    if(!isset($form_state['storage']['confirm'])){
        $form_state['storage']['confirm'] = TRUE; 
        $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
        //this is where the first form's submit would go
        //you can stuff some info into $form_state if you need it
    }
    else{
        //this is where the second form's submit would go
    }
}
```